# Задержка функции в микросекундах Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Как в Android реализовать задержку функции с точностью в микросекундах?

Comment: Точную - никак, даже миллисекундную, потому что ОС многозадачна, ядер процессора не хватает на сотни потоков и они на самом деле выполняются не совсем параллельно, а чередуясь. А вообще, принцип такой: while и tick'и процессора, заодно ваш while, будучи без Sleep, нагрузит хотя бы одно ядро и "потеснит" другие процессы.

Comment: @Rou1997 и заодно замедлит, а местами и полностью остановит все остальные приложения, в том числе фоновые сервисы, но хуже всего то, что это высадит в считанные минуты батарею. За busy loop программистов надо жестоко карать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Естественно, "потеснит" = замедлит. Зато задержка будет точнее :) А батарея, так от USB или повербанка работать будем :) Ну а правильным было бы вообще платформу менять на какой-нибудь микроконтроллер..

Comment: @Rou1997 если от usb, то это уже не телефон будет, а грелка :)